# Lock CToolbar derived class position after RestoreState

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

This question have been asked before but no working solutions was given.
I want to lock the docked position of one toolbar when the user has finished to configure his personal layout.
I'm using my own derived class from CToolbar.
I've already tried most of the given suggestions when you google for "CToolBar lock position" and similar but with no success.
Any help?